# Calculating new image size - how can I make this more efficient/shorter

Tags: php, image-resizing, dimensions

I have a script, that's pretty huge for an actual simple task, because it's nested very often. What it does is this:

- get the current size of an image
- get the new maximum dimensions
- calculate the dimensions the image is going to be resized to (aspect ratio is always kept):

  - if image is smaller than new dimensions: keep original size
  - if max new dimensions have an x and y-value: scale image to fit both values
  - if max new dimensions have only a x-value: scale to fit at least x
  - if max new dimensions have only a y-value: scale to fit at least y

This is the script:

```
//example values, whereas 'new' is the maximum range for the new image
$dimensions = array(1920,1200);
$dimensionsNew  = array(160, 0);
// percentage the image must be scaled
$percentages    = array(0,0);

//calculate scale range
if ($dimensionsNew[0] != 0) $percentages[0] = $dimensions[0] / $dimensionsNew[0];
if ($dimensionsNew[1] != 0) $percentages[1] = $dimensions[1] / $dimensionsNew[1];

//get new dimensions
if ( ($dimensions[0] <= $dimensionsNew[0]) && ($dimensions[1] <= $dimensionsNew[1]) ) {
    $dimensionsNew[0]       = $dimensions[0];
    $dimensionsNew[1]       = $dimensions[1];
} elseif ($dimensionsNew[0] == 0) {
    if ($dimensions[1] <= $dimensionsNew[1]) {
        $dimensionsNew[0]   = $dimensions[0];
        $dimensionsNew[1]   = $dimensions[1];
    } else {
        $dimensionsNew[0]   = ceil($dimensions[0] / $percentages[1]);
    }
} elseif ($dimensionsNew[1] == 0) {
    if ($dimensions[0] <= $dimensionsNew[0]) {
        $dimensionsNew[0]   = $dimensions[0];
        $dimensionsNew[1]   = $dimensions[1];
    } else {
        $dimensionsNew[1]   = ceil($dimensions[1] / $percentages[0]);
    }
} elseif ($percentages[0] < $percentages[1]) {
    $dimensionsNew[1]       = ceil($dimensions[1] / $percentages[1]);
} else {
    $dimensionsNew[0]       = ceil($dimensions[0] / $percentages[0]);
}
```

It does what it should do. But is there an easier way of doing this? I think I looked at this code too often and can't find a way to optimize.

Comment: Just a comment re code readability, naming your array elements like `$dimensions = array(x = 1920, y = 1200);` will let you refer to x & y later.

Comment: Ah good thinking. Easier to maintain than 0|1 - I can see that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use "min" on the rations of the sizes to work out the scale required. In this is >1 then no shrinking ncessary, if <1 then shrink by the right amount

```
//example values, whereas 'new' is the maximum range for the new image
$dimensions = array(1920,1200);
$dimensionsNew  = array(160, 0);   // NOTE: 0 won't work, but it's your example ;)

// What scale do we need to go to
$scaleRequired = min($dimensionsNew[0] / $dimensions[0], $dimensionsNew[1] / $dimensions[1]);

if ($scaleRequired < 1) {
    $finalDimensions = array (
         $dimensions[0] * $scaleRequired, 
         $dimensions[1] * $scaleRequired);

    // Resize to $finalDimensions

} else {
    // Do nothing
}
```

Comment: `0 won't work, but it's your example ;)` - why not? What should he use instead when specifying that `y` is not restricted? You won't end up with a division by zero unless the old dimensions have a zero in them - which is obviously impossible.

Comment: The `min` function is pretty sleek here. So this will do that the image will always fit into new dimensionsm, when both are given. It won't work for the other cases, am I right? In the example (160,0) the image will be scaled to fit 160px width and the height is calculated from the aspect ratio.

Comment: I read this as "Max X dimension is 160, max Y dimension is 0" which is why I said it won't work - as the min rules that out. If you want to allow 0 as "allow anything" then you will need some "jiggery pokery" or simply set at 999999 which essentially rules it out of the equation.

Comment: @DaveRandom - see comment above (to OP). The 0 will result in 0 being the resultant size with my solution - why I said it won't work. But setting it to an extreme upper bound such as 999999 will effectively take it out of the equation.

Comment: @Robbie Oh yeh, obvious now you point it out. I need more tea I think. +1

Comment: This one is pretty nice and simple. Many thanks for your effort. I really do like it. :) And thanks for the hint to take the second variable out of the equation.